Why ts with modifier `?` can't be infered?
type OriginalParams = [a: number, b?: string | undefined, c?: { cc: 1;} | undefined]; 


type NewParams = OriginalParams extends [infer A, infer B, ...any] ? [A, B?]: never;

I want to get the first two element from OriginalParams, but the NewParams will be never.
If I let b to be actually required like:
type OriginalParams = [a: number, b: string | undefined, c?: {
    cc: 1;} | undefined]

It can be right like [number, (string | undefined)].
I want to know why ? will interfered infer.

Never is a typo, it's never

• What does "signal" mean in the title? • Optional elements are not assignable to required elements; vice versa is fine, though, so you could write it this way if you wanted. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

? is the signal I understand. Your code is right. ()? is exactly what I need.

The term "signal" isn't conventional. You should call it a modifier instead.

I see, thank you.

Hm, I'm not certain my answer is quite the best approach...
But adapting from the example in the Docs:
type Flatten<Type> = Type extends Array<infer Item> ? Item : Type;

Perhaps this is what you'll need to do?
type NewParams = OriginalParams extends [infer A, (infer B)?, ...(infer Rest)] ? [A, B?, ...Rest] : never;

Here I've extended this to include the rest and removed the undefined from  OriginalParams (since they're optional (?), it's already implied)
type OriginalParams = [a: number, b?: string, c?: { cc: 1;}];  


type NewParams = OriginalParams extends [infer A, (infer B)?, ...(infer Rest)] ? [A, B?, ...Rest] : never;

// These are valid
const newParams1: NewParams  = [1];
const newParams2: NewParams  = [1, ""];
const newParams3: NewParams  = [1, "", {cc: 1}];


// These show errors
const newParamsError1: NewParams  = [""];
const newParamsError2: NewParams  = [1, 2];
const newParamsError3: NewParams  = [1, "", {cc: 2}];
const newParamsError4: NewParams  = [1, "", {cc: 1}, 2];

Playground

Doesn't this just result in never? How is that an improvement? Could you [edit] to explain how the output is intended to be used?

That's weird, when I was on the playground it wasn't doing that...maybe I posted the wrong code

Ok I've resolved that issue, I think I copied the wrong code over (my bad!)

The problem that you have optional tuple members and TS doesn't know an actual shape of your tuple so it cannot infer. You could make some complex conditional type to handle this, but in your case maybe it's easier just use index access:
Playground
type OriginalParams = [a: number, b?: string, c?: { cc: 1;}];  

type NewParams = [OriginalParams[0], OriginalParams[1]?];

